# How to read into memory the lines of a text file from an IFormFile in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: parsing, file-upload, asp.net-core

Say you have this Action:

```cs
public List<string> Index(IFormFile file){

    //extract list of strings from the file
    return new List<string>();
}
```

I've found plenty of examples of saving the file to the drive, but what if I instead want to skip this and just read the lines of text into an array in memory, directly from the IFormFile?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The abstraction for the `IFormFile` has an [`.OpenReadStream`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/87cd79d6fc54bb4abf07c1e380cd7a9498a78612/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/IFormFile.cs#L48) method.
To prevent a ton of undesirable and potentially large allocations, we should read a single line at a time and build up our list from each line that we read. Additionally, we could encapsulate this logic in an extension method. The `Index` action ends up looking like this:

```cs
public List<string> Index(IFormFile file) => file.ReadAsList();
```

The corresponding extension method looks like this:

```cs
public static List<string> ReadAsList(this IFormFile file)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            result.AppendLine(reader.ReadLine()); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Likewise you could have an `async` version as well:

```cs
public static async Task<string> ReadAsStringAsync(this IFormFile file)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            result.AppendLine(await reader.ReadLineAsync()); 
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Alternatively, you could you use an [`ObjectPool<StringBuilder>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/objectpool?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and modern C# 8 features.

```cs
public static async Task<string> ReadAsStringAsync(
    this IFormFile file, Object<StringBuilder> pool)
{
    var builder = pool.Get();
    try
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());
        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            builder.AppendLine(await reader.ReadLineAsync()); 
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        pool.Return(builder);
    }
}
```

Then you could use this version this way:

```cs
public Task<List<string>> Index(
    IFormFile file, [FromServices] ObjectPool<StringBuilder> pool) =>
    file.ReadAsListAsync(pool);
```

Comment: this worked, though it wouldn't accept Environment.NewLine so I used `Split('\n')`, something about wanting a char instead of a string

Comment: Why would you read it all into a single string then Split then make a list? Why not just read it line by line and add to a list? The above code allocates a potentially giant string, to then allocate an array, then allocates a list.

Comment: Great observation. I was simply showing how it could be done, I'll update the code - thanks.

Comment: @davidfowl better, or what else would you suggest?

Comment: Much better. The garbage collector thanks you. To do even better, we'd need to know what the consumer was doing with those lines. Maybe they don't ever need to be in a list all at the same time.

Comment: wouldn't it be much faster to use a StringBuilder since that is the fastest possible way to work with strings besides using Span<T>?

Answer (score 30):

ASP.NET Core 3.0 - Reading a form file's content into string

```cs
public static async Task<string> ReadFormFileAsync(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult((string)null);
    }
    
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```